# Directed graph and Dijkstra algorithm using heap

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, graph, pathfinding

I have implemented directed graph and Dijkstra algorithm using heap in Python.

I first implemented an abstract base class `WeightedGraph`, of which `DirectedGraph` is a subclass. The `DirectedGraph` uses an adjacency map as its internal representation. I then implemented the method `single_source_shortest_paths`, which uses the Dijkstra algorithm, which in turn uses a `HeapQueue` that I implemented in another module `heap_queue`.

Before going to the codes, let's look at an example.

**An Example**

We can add nodes and edges as usual. When adding an edge, if any node in the edge does not already exist, that node is automatically added.

```
>>> g = DirectedGraph()
>>> g.add_node(0)
>>> g.add_node(1)
>>> g.add_node(2)
>>>
>>> g.add_edge(start=0, end=1, weight=3)
>>> g.add_edge(start=1, end=2, weight=2)
>>> g.add_edge(start=3, end=4, weight=3)
>>> g.add_edge(start=4, end=3, weight=2)
>>> g.add_edge(start=0, end=3, weight=1)
>>> g.add_edge(start=3, end=1, weight=1)
>>> g.add_edge(start=2, end=4, weight=1)
```

In the above, when adding the edge `(3, 4)`, the nodes `3` and `4` are automatically added. The graph `g` now looks like this:

[image]

We can list out all the nodes, edges and out-neighbors of a given node. Each edge is represented as a `namedtuple`.

```
>>> list(g.nodes)
[0, 1, 2, 4, 3]
>>>
>>> for edge in g.edges:
...     print(edge)
DirectedEdge(start=0, end=1, weight=3)
DirectedEdge(start=0, end=3, weight=1)
DirectedEdge(start=1, end=2, weight=2)
DirectedEdge(start=2, end=4, weight=1)
DirectedEdge(start=4, end=3, weight=2)
DirectedEdge(start=3, end=4, weight=3)
DirectedEdge(start=3, end=1, weight=1)
>>>
>>> for neighbor, weight in g.neighbors(3):
...     print(f'neighbor={neighbor}, weight={weight}')
neighbor=4, weight=3
neighbor=1, weight=1
```

Now comes the meat, the `single_source_shortest_paths` method, which finds the shortest paths to multiple targets from a single source. It returns a dictionary whose keys are the given targets and values are the corresponding shortest paths.

```
>>> g.single_source_shortest_paths(start=0, targets=range(5))
{0: [0],
1: [0, 3, 1],
2: [0, 3, 1, 2],
3: [0, 3],
4: [0, 3, 4]}
```

If any target is unreachable, its path is simply an empty list.

```
>>> g.single_source_shortest_paths(start=4, targets=[0, 2])
{0: [],
2: [4, 3, 1, 2]}
```

**The Code**

The code of `WeightedGraph` and `DirectedGraph` is as follow:

```
import abc
from collections import namedtuple

from heap_queue import HeapQueue

DirectedEdge = namedtuple('DirectedEdge', 'start end weight')
INF = float('inf')


class WeightedGraph(abc.ABC):
    """An abstract base class for a weighted graph."""

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def add_node(self, label):
        """Add a node with the given label.
        No effect if a node with the given label already exists.
        """

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def add_edge(self, start, end, weight):
        """Add an edge from start to end with the given weight.
        Add the nodes automatically if not already exist.
        Overwrite the weight if the edge already exists.
        """

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def remove_node(self, label):
        """Remove the node with the given label.
        Remove all edges at the node automatically.
        Raise a ValueError if the node does not exist.
        """

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def remove_edge(self, start, end):
        """Remove the edge from start to end.
        Raise a ValueError if the edge does not exist
        """

    @property
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def nodes(self):
        """Return an iterator over all nodes."""

    @property
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def edges(self):
        """Return an iterator over all edges."""

    @property
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def node_count(self):
        """Return the number of nodes."""

    @property
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def edge_count(self):
        """Return the number of edges."""

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def neighbors(self, label):
        """Return an iterator, in which each item is an (neighbor, weight) pair,
        where neighbor is an out-neighbor of the node with the given label and
        weight is the weight of the corresponding edge.
        Raise a ValueError if the node does not exist.
        """

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def degree(self, label):
        """Return the (out-)degree of the node with the given label.
        Raise a ValueError if the node does not exist.
        """

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def weight(self, start, end):
        """Return the weight of the edge from start to end.
        Raise a ValueError if the edge does not exist.
        """


class DirectedGraph(WeightedGraph):
    """Implement a directed weighted graph using adjacency map."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the graph with an adjacency map."""
        self._adjacency = {}

    def add_node(self, label):
        # if no such node, initialize the corresponding neighbour dict
        self._adjacency.setdefault(label, {})

    def add_edge(self, start, end, weight):
        self._adjacency.setdefault(end, {})

        # extract the neighbour dict of start and set weight
        nbr_dict = self._adjacency.setdefault(start, {})
        nbr_dict[end] = weight

    def remove_node(self, label):
        if label not in self._adjacency:
            raise ValueError(f'no node {label}')

        else:
            del self._adjacency[label]

            # delete all edges whose end node is the given node
            for _, nbr_dict in self._adjacency.items():
                nbr_dict.pop(label, None)

    def remove_edge(self, start, end):
        try:
            del self._adjacency[start][end]

        # Two cases result in a KeyError
        # Case 1: start node does not exist, or
        # Case 2: start node exists but no edge from it to the end node
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError(f'no edge from {start} to {end}')

    @property
    def nodes(self):
        yield from self._adjacency

    @property
    def edges(self):
        """Iterate over all edges. Each edge is represented as a namedtuple
        of the form DirectedEdge(start, end, weight).
        """
        for start, nbr_dict in self._adjacency.items():
            for end, weight in nbr_dict.items():
                yield DirectedEdge(start, end, weight)

    @property
    def node_count(self):
        return len(self._adjacency)

    @property
    def edge_count(self):
        return sum(len(nbr_dict) for nbr_dict in self._adjacency.values())

    def neighbors(self, label):
        if label not in self._adjacency:
            raise ValueError(f'no node {label}')

        # return iter instead of yield from, otherwise ValueError is never
        # raised upon the initialization of the generator
        else:
            nbr_dict = self._adjacency[label]
            return iter(nbr_dict.items())

    def degree(self, label):
        if label not in self._adjacency:
            raise ValueError(f'no node {label}')
        else:
            return len(self._adjacency[label])

    def weight(self, start, end):
        try:
            return self._adjacency[start][end]

        # similar to remove_edge, two cases result in a KeyError
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError(f'no edge from {start} to {end}')

    def single_source_shortest_paths(self, start, targets):
        """Find the shortest paths to multiple targets from a single source.
        Return a dictionary whose keys are the given targets and values are the
        corresponding shortest paths.
        """
        targets = list(targets)

        # check all nodes exist
        if start not in self._adjacency:
            raise ValueError(f'no node {start}')
        for target in targets:
            if target not in self._adjacency:
                raise ValueError(f'no node {target}')

        # use dijkstra to obtain the shortest-path tree, which
        # is then used to construct a path for each target
        result = {}
        came_from = self._dijkstra(start, targets)

        for target in targets:
            if target not in came_from:
                # no path from start to target
                path = []
            else:
                path = DirectedGraph._construct_path(came_from, target)
            result[target] = path

        return result

    def _dijkstra(self, start, targets):
        """A helper method that implements the Dijkstra algorithm.
        Return the shortest-path tree represented as a dict came_from.
        """
        came_from = {start: None}
        targets = set(targets)

        # initialize the cost of every node to be infinity, except the start
        frontier = HeapQueue((node, INF) for node in self.nodes)
        frontier.push(start, 0)

        while targets:
            # node popped from the queue already has its shortest path found,
            # can be safely discarded
            cur_node, cur_cost = frontier.pop()
            targets.discard(cur_node)

            for nxt_node, weight in self.neighbors(cur_node):
                # only relax the nodes to which shortest paths are not yet found
                if nxt_node in frontier:
                    nxt_cost = cur_cost + weight

                    # if new cost less than the current cost, update it
                    if nxt_cost < frontier[nxt_node]:
                        frontier.push(nxt_node, nxt_cost)
                        came_from[nxt_node] = cur_node

        return came_from

    @staticmethod
    def _construct_path(came_from, target):
        """Given the shortest-path tree came_from,
        find the path from start to the given target.
        """
        cur_node = target
        path = []

        # backtrack from target until hitting the beginning
        while cur_node is not None:
            path.append(cur_node)
            cur_node = came_from[cur_node]

        # the path is in the reversed order
        path.reverse()
        return path
```

In the module `heap_queue`, the code of `HeapQueue` is as follow:

```
class HeapQueue:
    """Implement a priority queue in the form of a min-heap.
    Each entry is an (item, key) pair. Item with a lower key has a higher priority.
    Item must be hashable and unique. No duplicate items.
    Pushing an existing item would update its key instead.
    """

    def __init__(self, entries=None):
        """
        :argument:
        entries (iterable of tuples): an iterable of (item, key) pairs
        """
        if entries is None:
            self._entries = []
            self._indices = {}
        else:
            self._entries = list(entries)
            self._indices = {item: idx for idx, (item, _) in enumerate(self._entries)}
            self._heapify()

    def _heapify(self):
        """Enforce the heap properties upon initializing the heap."""
        start = len(self) // 2 - 1
        for idx in range(start, -1, -1):
            self._down(idx)

    def __contains__(self, item):
        """Return True if the item is in the heap."""
        return item in self._indices

    def __len__(self):
        """Number of entries remaining in the heap."""
        return len(self._entries)

    def __iter__(self):
        """Iterate over all items."""
        for item, _ in self._entries:
            yield item

    """Helper methods"""

    def _swap(self, idx1, idx2):
        """Swap two entries."""
        item1, _ = self._entries[idx1]
        item2, _ = self._entries[idx2]
        self._indices[item1] = idx2
        self._indices[item2] = idx1
        self._entries[idx1], self._entries[idx2] = self._entries[idx2], self._entries[idx1]

    def _up(self, idx):
        """Bring a violating entry up to its correct position recursively."""
        if idx == 0:
            return

        parent = (idx - 1) // 2
        # compare key with the parent
        if self._entries[idx][1] < self._entries[parent][1]:
            self._swap(idx, parent)
            self._up(parent)

    def _smaller_child(self, idx):
        """Find the child with smaller key. If no child, return None."""
        left = 2 * idx + 1
        # case 1: no child
        if left >= len(self):
            return None

        right = left + 1
        # case 2: only left child
        if right == len(self):
            return left

        # case 3: two children
        if self._entries[left][1] < self._entries[right][1]:
            return left
        else:
            return right

    def _down(self, idx):
        """Bring a violating entry down to its correct position recursively."""
        child = self._smaller_child(idx)
        if child is None:
            return

        # compare key with the child with smaller key
        if self._entries[idx][1] > self._entries[child][1]:
            self._swap(idx, child)
            self._down(child)

    """Priority queue operations"""

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        """Return the key of an item.
        If the item does not exist, raise a KeyError."""
        if item not in self._indices:
            raise KeyError(f"{item} not found")

        idx = self._indices[item]
        _, key = self._entries[idx]
        return key

    def peek(self):
        """Return the item with the minimum key."""
        item, _ = self._entries[0]
        return item

    def push(self, item, key):
        """Push an item into the heap with a given key.
        If the item already exists, update its key instead.
        """
        if item not in self._indices:
            # insert the new item to the end and bring it up to the correct position
            idx = len(self)
            self._entries.append((item, key))
            self._indices[item] = idx
            self._up(idx)
        else:
            # the item already exists, find its index and update its key
            idx = self._indices[item]
            item, old_key = self._entries[idx]
            self._entries[idx] = (item, key)

            # bring the entry to the correct position
            if key < old_key:
                self._up(idx)
            if key > old_key:
                self._down(idx)

    def pop(self):
        """Remove the item with the minimum key.
        The resulting (item, key) pair is also returned."""
        # after swapping the first and the last entry,
        # the required entry goes from the beginning to the end
        self._swap(0, len(self) - 1)
        item, key = self._entries.pop()

        del self._indices[item]
        self._down(0)
        return item, key
```

What improvement can I make on my code? Any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: We'll, first of all, in the `__init__` method of `HeapQueue` you can set the default value of the `entries` parameter to `[]` instead of `None`, and then get rid of the `if else`.

Comment: I thought we should never use mutable default arguments?

Comment: Oh I guess you are right, then